# Evaluate $\int_{2}^{\infty} \frac{x^2-x}{6^x} dx$

Tags: improper-integrals

Can someone please help me to solve

$$\int_{2}^{\infty} \frac{x^2-x}{6^x} \mathrm dx ?$$

I don't know how to integrate it as there is no exponential involved but the constant $6$.

Comment: There is exactly one real number such that, for all real numbers $x$, the idenity $e^{\alpha x}=\frac1{6^x}$ holds. The question for you is: which number is $\alpha$?

Comment: Have you considered integration by parts plus the fact that for some constant $b > 0$, $\frac{d}{dx} b^x = b^x \cdot \ln(b)$?

Comment: @G.Sassatelli I didn't change $1/6^{x}$ to $6^{-x}$?

Comment: @Mattos, he's is essentially trying to get OP to figure out how to differentiate $6^x$ knowing that $\frac{d}{dx} e^x = e^x$ and the chain rule. More generally, notice that $\frac{d}{dx} b^x = \frac{d}{dx} e^{\ln(b)x} = e^{\ln(b)x} \cdot \ln(b) = b^x \cdot \ln(b)$

Comment: @AlkaKadri Mate, G.Sassatelli and I were talking about an edit that was made to the question that he mistakenly attributed to me. He then removed his comment about the edit. Our exchange had nothing to do with understanding G.Sassatellis comment to the OP which is still visible.

Comment: @Mattos ah my bad bro, a misunderstanding on my part.

Comment: @AlkaKadri All good mate.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54856/discussion-between-alkakadri-and-mattos).

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on the comments. There *is* an exponential function.

Recall that for $a>0$,

$$a^x = (e^{\ln a})^x = e^{x\ln (a) },$$

so the integral can be rewritten as

$$\int_{2}^{\infty} (x^2-x)e^{-x\ln(6)}  \mathrm dx.$$

Got it from there?